# change header height on 2017 theme for logged in users

Tags: frontpage, theme-twenty-seventeen

When a guest sees the homepage they see the (almost) full height picture which is quite nice I think.

However, when a user logs in I'd like them to be redirected to the home page but with a much shorter picture (as the picture appears on the internal pages of the site).

I know I could redirect logged in users to a faux front page, but is there a way of changing the height of the main header picture depending if the user is a guest or logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress will automatically add a [body class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) to the body tag if a user is logged in.  You could potentially use this to adjust the height.

For example..

```
.logged-in #myElement {
    ...Your CSS
}
```

Something like this should work.

```
.logged-in.twentyseventeen-front-page.has-header-image .custom-header-media {
    height: calc(70vh);
}
```

Note the calc 70vh is 70% of viewport height, so adjust to what you need.

Comment: A very simple, elegant, not to mention fast, response and solution - thank you!